# Predicate verification of mocks in Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

Is there a way to ask Mockito if a method was called (like verify) but instead of exploding when false, it just would return true/false. Essentially I want to be able to query a mock object in some code I am writing that wraps Mockito, and then handle failures my own way.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I don't think there is something like that right now. However you can achieve that with a custom [`VerificationMode`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/verification/VerificationMode.html). You could proceed the same way as you will do with a classic *visitor* pattern, ie you create the `VerificationMode` instance, in the `verify` method you set some instance variable to either true or false, and finally later on you could check the result by querying your `VerificationMode` instance.

Note that you need *wrap* a verification mode and catch the exception it might throws. (`times(1)` is the default verification mode)

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you write your own `VerificationMode`, you shouldn't need to wrap it and catch the exception.  But it might be simpler just to wrap and catch an ordinary verify call, with one of the built-in verification modes.